# How to find PHP parse errors

Tags: php

I have a PHP script, util.php,  that I call from jQuery:

```
$("#galleryContent").load("util.php",
              {op : 'get_thumbs' 
                          },  
                          function() {
                   $('.galleryThumb').draggable(thumb_dragOps);

                          }
              );
```

Anything the script echoes shows up in #galleryContent.
But the script has acquired a bug such that nothing happens now when it's called.  Even if I put an

`echo ("In util.php");`

at the very top, this doesn't show up in #galleryContent. If I delete all of the code after the echo down to `?>` then the echo *does* show up.  So something is keeping util.php from parsing and running.  There's a missing ";" a missing "}", or something like that.

My question is, why isn't something telling me were that bug is?   I have

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

at the top of the script but these seem to only help with run time errors, not parse errors.  What can I use to find a parse error?

Thanks.

Comment: `ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);` also try cutting out the middle man, go to the script directly in your browser

Comment: Have you checked your networks tab to see if the script executes and if the response is present?

Comment: Assuming that you're not using Notepad, a decent editor will tell you where the parse error is.

Comment: I'm using Dreamweaver CS4. It looks like they didn't add PHP syntax help until CS5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing errors cannot be configured in run-time via ini_set or error_reporting, you need to use php.ini set [display-startup-errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors) to 1 and restart apache

second - you can try run `php -l <filename>` to get syntax errors

Comment: It can't? Unless I'm reading it wrong, the manual seems to say it can http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: @CrayonViolent theoretically - you can, but if file is not parsed because of syntax errors these instructions will not be executed